# How do we get two random values from min and max but with a gap of 500?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a database table that has over 80,000 rows. Unfortunately my queries use `ORDER BY RAND()` and I am starting to see it affecting the CPU. I decided to go with removing `ORDER BY RAND()` and instead do something like `id>=500 (random value) && id<=1000 (random value)` so the WHERE clause will search 500 rows randomly each time.

Basically what I need is something in PHP to grab the MIN and MAX id values and generate two random numbers, one MUST be larger than the other by `500` (so 500 sequential gap). The result should look something like:

```
$min_id = 500;
$max_id = 80000;
// result should pick random number but make sure there's a gap of 500.
$min_random_value = 578;
$max_random_value = 1078;
```

etc. Is this possible?

I know I can just pick a random value from `min, max` and add or subtract 500 to it. My concern is what if the random value is 79999 and adding 500 to that would make it invalid.

Comment: There may be a MySQL statement that someone more savvy in MySQL could come up with rather than relying 100% on php. I am not very advance in mysql besides basic stuff so that savvy person is not me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate one random number with php like:

```
$min = rand(500, $max_id);
```

And then add 500 to the generated number to get the max value:

```
$min = rand(500, $max_id);
$max = $min + 500;
```

to ensure that your `$max` number is not greater than 80 000(`$max_id`), do an if statement:

```
  $max_id = 80000;
  $min = rand(500, $max_id);
  $max = $min + 500;
  if($max > $max_id)
   {
        $max = $min;
        $min = $min - 500;
   }
```

Comment: This does not take into account the size of the table.

Comment: Why not to subtract gap from max in the first step? And not to check it in the end.

Comment: @AntonM. that would mean if he does this in the where clause `id>= (random value) && id<= (random value)`,  id's that are greater than `70500` will always be excluded

Comment: He calculates min with random and max = min + 500. If he generate min 70500, then max = 80000. Actually bottom answer is about it, i did not see it when wrote comment.

Comment: Hey, this is exactly what I was looking for! I think there's a typo towards the end though, with the if statement the $min should = $max - 500; otherwise the $min could be a value lower than the smallest id. Again, thanks a lot, you're awesome!

Comment: @user3186337 it seems like `$min` and `$max` have the same value at that point, so it doesn't matter which one he used. anyway great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$max_id  = total rows in your table;
$max_val = $max_id-500;
$start   = rand(1, $max_val);
$sql     = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT $start , 500";
```